# Error - LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.IFormatProvider)'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am converting MVC3 linq-to-sql to MVC5 Entity Framework 6.1; I used the following helper for dropdown list:

```
public static string ExDropDownList (this HtmlHelper helper, string name, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList, bool readOnly, object htmlAttributes)
{
    string html = "";
    if (readOnly)
    {
        foreach (SelectListItem item in selectList)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                html = String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", name, item.Text);
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    else
        html = AddEmptyOption(System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(helper, name, selectList, htmlAttributes).ToString());
    return html;
}
```

I generate this list using:

```
var proviences = lookupRepository.GetProviences();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListProvience =  from p in proviences
   select new SelectListItem
   {
      Text = p.ProvinceName,
      Value = p.ProvinceID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    };
```

I get the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to materialise the query before you invoke ToString().

```
var proviences = lookupRepository.GetProviences();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListProvience = (from p in proviences).AsEnumerable()
  .Select(p => new SelectListItem
  {
     Text = p.ProvinceName,
    ....
```

but it could be just

```
var proviences = lookupRepository.GetProviences();
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListProvience = proviences.Select(p => new SelectListItem
{
  Text = p.ProvinceName,
```

or easier still

```
SeelctList selectListProvience = new SelectList(proviences, "ProvinceID", "ProvinceName");
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your helper supposed to do?

Comment: The helper was to generate the dropsownlist in the view:  @Html.ExDropDownList("ProvinceID", Model.Proviences, Model.IsReadOnly, new{style = "background-color:#FFFFE7"}).  I used it in aspx but it is not working in Rzaor, I see the list but not formated.  I will try to use twitterbootstrap. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The code for the helper makes no sense and I'm not sure what your expecting the rendered html to be based on the value of `readOnly`. If you post another question explaining what your trying to achieve then perhaps I or someone else can help. And I recommend you study the MVC source code to see how html helpers should be coded.

Comment: I use readOnly because there are two types of users.  I got it working with twitterbootstrapMVC.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework is trying to convert this to SQL, which fails because it can't handle `ToString()`. Try  adding a `ToList()` instead:

```
var proviences = lookupRepository.GetProviences().ToList();
```

This causes the query to execute, but this is fine if you're selecting every item in the list anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, I will be using Stephen third solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when separated my model project 
I removed `using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;` and replaced it with `using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;` and issue was gone